# What are the best practices when it comes to redirecting to the previous page after login? PHP

Tags: php, security, redirect, authentication, code-injection

After logging in, I want to redirect users back to the page they were on using PHP. After doing a little searching on the matter and not finding any good solutions, I decided to add a hidden field to the login form which contains the current partial-URL using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].
The server uses this information to redirect the user back to the previous page after logging them in. This has been working correctly, however here is my question.

Overall, what security measures do I need to apply to the url, once it is returned to the server, so that, if tampered with, it will not redirect the user to an external and possibly scrupulous site?

Ex: if I change the value in the form from $_SESSION['REQUEST_URI'] to http://www.google.com, it redirects to Google after login. What is the best way to sanitize this?

*I am currently using mysql_real_escape_string() for SQL injection purposes.

```
<form action="/signin/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
</form>
......
$return = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['return']);
header('Location: '.$return);
```

Comment: Why do you use `mysql_real_escape` if you save the URL only in a session? What about `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: I'm not saving the URL in a session, it is the value of a hidden form field, which gets passed to signin.php, which should redirect back to the page on my site from which the user logged in. As for $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], it suffers the same security problems as those I'm facing now. It also didn't work when I first tried using it.

Answer (score 2):

As hundreds of other answers/comments have pointed out, everyone should be using `mysqli` by now. That aside,  `mysql_real_escape_string()` is—as the name implies—for escaping strings that are going to be used in a MySQL query. There is no other use for it. It does *not* protect you from XSS, as I'll demonstrate...

Setup:

```
// represent a string without using quotes
function ab($str) {
  $out = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    ($chr = _ab($str[$i])) || ($chr = 'String.fromCharCode('.ord($str[$i]).')');
  }
  return implode('+', $out);
}
// represent a character without quotes
function _ab($chr) { 
  $alpha = array(
    'Array', 'Boolean', 'Date', 'Function', 'Iterator', 'Number', 'Object',
    'RegExp', 'String', 'ArrayBuffer', 'Float32Array', 'Float64Array', 'JSON',
    'Int16Array', 'Int32Array', 'Int8Array', 'Uint16Array', 'Uint32Array',
    'Uint8Array', 'Uint8ClampedArray', 'Error', 'EvalError', 'InternalError',
    'RangeError', 'ReferenceError', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'parseInt',
    'TypeError', 'URIError', 'decodeURI', 'decodeURIComponent', 'encodeURI',
    'encodeURIComponent', 'eval', 'isFinite', 'isNaN', 'parseFloat', 'uneval'
  );
  // sort function names by length to minimize output
  usort($alpha, function($a, $b){return strlen($a) - strlen($b);});
  foreach ($alpha as $fn) {
    if (($i = strpos($fn, $chr)) !== false) return "$fn.name[$i]";
  }
  return false;
}
$mb = chr(0xC2).chr(0x8F); // eats backslashes for breakfast
```

How it works:

```
$msg = ab('exploited!');
$payload = "console.log($msg);";
$uri = "$mb\" onmouseover=$payload title=XSS";
// try to sanitize URI
$uri = mysql_real_escape_string($uri);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $uri ?>">click me</a>
```

This generates "URIs" like:

```
" onmouseover=console.log(Date.name[2]+eval.name[0]+isNaN.name[1]+Date.name[2]); title=hi
```

which slips right through `mysql_real_escape_string()` (because the first "character" is actually a partial multibyte character `0xC28F` which eats the character immediately after it—the backslash `mysql_real_escape_string()` inserts to escape the quotation mark), producing:

```
<a href="\" onmouseover=THE_PAYLOAD title=XSS">click me</a>
```

Which the browser interprets as:

```
<a title="XSS"" onmouseover="THE_PAYLOAD" href="\">click me</a>
```

You can test this yourself in Firefox or IE with a console open, and you will see that arbitrary JS code is being executed when you hover over the link, despite the use of `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

`mysql_real_escape_string()` also doesn't protect you from `javascript:` links like:

```
javascript:$.post(%27/account/change-password%27,{newPassword:%27p0wned%27,newPassword2:%27p0wned%27});undefined;
```

Since percent-encoding isn't used in MySQL, `mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't know that `%27` is a single-quote or that `%22` is a double-quote; so it just ignores them. If the user clicks this link, it'll send a `POST` request changing their password to one chosen by the attacker. It can be modified to also redirect to the page the user expects to go to, so they'll have no idea of what's just happened.

The only obstacle to this type of attack on your current setup is that URIs are root-relative, so they always start with a "/", but as the first example shows, multibyte strings can be used to trick browsers, and even if the resultant markup is broken, the link will still work due to the leniency of most browsers' HTML parser. This example took me only 15 minutes to come up with after reading your question. A determined attacker could no doubt come up with something that *does* pose a practical threat.

So to be safe, you have to sanitize your URI using methods specifically designed for HTML and URLs. [OWASP's guidelines on URL escaping](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.235_-_URL_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_URL_Parameter_Values) are a good place to start. Otherwise, the other answers here offer some safer alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll certainly look into XSS more, however for this application alone, would it not then be simpler to use session variables to keep track of the url and not worry about URL escaping?

Answer (score 1):

I found this, which looks really good to me: [Safely Redirecting with an Open URL Parameter in PHP](http://www.savagereactor.co.uk/posts/2008/12/14_safely_redirecting_with_a_url_parameter.html)

He's working with a trusted list of "referers".

Including this, you could work with several ways. Checking the referer, the hidden field in your form and if you're able to, even the server logs.

Except for the server logs, I don't think there's a better way to check where the user came from.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the current url in a session variable like in `$_SESSION["last_page_visited"]` (except on the login and login submit page). So every time you visit a new page, `$_SESSION["last_page_visited"]` will be overwritten with the current url. So, no matter which page you visit, the url to last page you visited is saved in the session. And from any page if you click login, after successful login redirect to the url held in that session. And if $_SESSION["last_page_visited"] is empty redirect to index page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works except for when the user has more than one browser window open for the same session, then they get redirected to the last page, even if it's the last page from the other browser.

Comment: You could avoid this problem by saving the URI to `$_SESSION['last_page'][$token]` and redirecting to `/login?token=$token`. This directly ties the window/tab to the redirect source. You could use `time()` or `microtime()` as the token, so that you can just keep the 10 newest URIs.

Answer (score 0):

If the login page is encrypted with SSL/TLS, and you set the value for the hidden form field from the server (which was verified against your whitelist), then if it gets modified before it's submitted, the user knows about it because they did it.

SSL/TLS is the best practice.